# What is the asymptotic time complexity of the following piece of code?

Tags: algorithm

How do you come up with the Big O notation?

```
float sum = 0 ; 
    for ( int i = 1; i < n ; i++)
    {
    sum + = A[i];
    }
    cout << sum;
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Evaluating_run-time_complexity gives some help on how to do this in general.

Comment: @ghost no of course you are right - total brain wreck moment.

Answer (score 2):

Great that you asked this. I just went over this in class and asked the same question. The Big O notation is used to describe how efficient or complex your algorithm is.

O(1) is an algorithm that execute in the same time. This is the most efficient type of algorithm. For example

```
bool bigO(String[] big)
{
if(big[0] == null)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

There is also O(N) which will depend on the size of the input. For example

```
bool bigO(String[] strings, String value)
{
for(int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
{
    if(strings[i] == value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

As you can tell this method can take longer to execute depending on the input. If the strings.Length was small it would be quick but if it was a large length it would take a while.

And then there is O(N^2). This involves multiple loops within it self. It can be O(N^3) depending on how deep you nested your iterations. For example

```
bool bigO(String[] strings)
{
for(int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < strings.Length; j++)
    {
        if(i == j) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(strings[i] == strings[j])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Now by looking at your algorithm what do you think yours is?
If you said O(N) you're right. Big O notation is dependent on how efficient your algorithm is. Efficiency can depend on 
CPU (time) usage,
,memory usage
,disk usage
and network usage

Comment: Avoid using the O(N) notation when you didn't define what N stands for.

Comment: This analysis is a bit superficial and deserves some precisions. The running time will vary as a function of the contents of the strings: the search can be immediately successful or not; it can also fail; this is why it makes sense to focus on the worst-case behavior. The worst case of the second algorithm is when the search fails; every given string is compared to the target; at worst, a string comparison takes as long as the shortest string is; assuming that the target is as long as any given string, the worst-case time is O(M), where M denotes the total number of *characters* in the strings

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code, the only parameter that will influence the running time is `n` (the actual values of the `A[i]`'s do not matter as the time for a floating-point addition does not depend on the operand values - at least as a first approximation). So the running time is analyzed as a function of `n`.

We have two assignments and an output statement (`sum= 0`, `i= 1`, `cout sum`) executed once. We also see a loop that is taken exactly `n-1` times; it executes a comparison, two integer additions and a jump (`i < n`, `i++`, `sum+= A[i]`, `for`).

Assuming that all the primitive operations take a constant amount of time, we can conclude that the running time is exactly `A + B.n`, for two constants `A` and `B`.

In asymptotic terms (i.e. when `n` gets as large as you want), you only care about the overall behavior of the function. So you just look at the dominant term `A.n`, and you even hide the constant `A`. This is why you say that the running time is bounded above by `O(n)`, called linear time.